# Should we have an IOT or internet-of-things tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

That's pretty much the question. Would it be useful to have an internet-of-things tag?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a huge long term benefit for this tag.

I often think that tagging is overused and stuff is often not tagged correctly. In this case, an IoT tag doesn't really define the question (it'd be like a toaster tag). It defines the type of project, which isn't that helpful.

Tags like Ethernet, WiFi, Arduino Uno, programming, etc. are much more descriptive and they seem more useful and worthwhile to me. This tag would replace the more helpful tags on some questions.

Answer (score -2):

Yes ! It's very used, and specific ! 
Because some softwares are dedicated to IoT and some protocols are mostly used only for that,
 so adding this tag can help people to find some new possibilitys that they didn't know like to (to be continued ... )

Comment: Can you please edit your post to indicate why this tag would be useful for our community? Thanks!

Comment: Then tag the specific protocols involved.